# Convergence of the limit of a series involving Möbius and Floor functions

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions, mobius-function, mobius-inversion

Studying and working with some problems involving the Möbius function, I (erroneously and somewhat randomly) found the following series/limit. I am curious about it, since I don't know wether it converges or not.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{1 \le n < x} \mu(n) \left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor \log \left ( 1-\frac{n}{x} \right )$$

Since

$$\sum_{1 \le n < x} \log \left ( 1-\frac{n}{x} \right )=O(x)$$

Or

$$O\left ( \sum_{1 \le n \le x} 1 \right )$$

And by Generalised Möbius Inversion we know that

$$1= \sum_{1 \le n \le x} \mu(n) \left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor$$

It seems reasonable for the limit to converge to a constant.

However, we are not allowed to use traditional methods to work with it for a lot of reasons (no integral tests, no summation by parts, etc.).

Any hint towards the solution of the problem or advice about how to approach to this kind of series and limits would be useful. Thank you very much.

Comment: $n=x$ causes the log term to blowup. So is it $1\leq n<x$?

Comment: @Alex That's right, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we set
$$
f(x) = \sum_{1 \le n < x} \mu(n) \left \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \right \rfloor \log \left ( 1-\frac{n}{x} \right ),
$$
then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ cannot exist. Note that when $p$ is prime, none of the individual summands changes when $x$ goes from just below $p$ to just above $p$; therefore the change in $f(x)$ near $x=p$ is only from the new term $\mu(p) \left \lfloor \frac{x}{p} \right \rfloor \log \left ( 1-\frac{p}{x} \right ) = -\log \left ( 1-\frac{p}{x} \right )$. This function is unbounded for $x$ near $p$, so $f(x)$ is not even bounded, let alone convergent as $x\to\infty$.

Even if we restrict $x$ to integers, setting $x=p+1$ results in a new term of size $\log p$ or so, which is still unbounded. (One then has to deal with the terms where $n$ divides $p+1$, but the total change in those terms is $\ll \tau(p+1)$, the number of divisors of $p+1$, and that is $o(\log p)$.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. You take into account only the case of prime numbers, but wouldn't there be any cancellation of terms for values of $n$ such that $\mu(n)=-1$? If not, how does the series that equals 1 in my question work?

Comment: Prime numbers are the easiest to analyze, but I suspect there are similar discontinuities in $f(x)$ at nearly all numbers. The simpler series is different: there the terms that change always change by $\pm1$ (rather than by different, unbounded amounts), and the Möbius function conspires to have all those changes cancel out each time.

Comment: But why doesn't that cancellation phenomenon happen in $$1=\sum \mu(n) \lfloor \frac{x}{n} \rfloor$$?

Comment: @user3141592: because without the log term, the above summands are bounded  by $x$

Comment: @Alex And here they are bounded by $ log(\frac{1}{x})$, which grows faster than $x$ but is also a bound, isn't it?. I mean, I see the point of the answer, and I understand that the sum over the values of $n$ for it a prime generates a fast growing function. What I do not understand is why won't it be contrarrested with, for example, the sum of $n$ for which $\mu(n)=1$